# How to enable history back button when using location.href = "site"?

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history

I am new to js and html. I have a js code to redirect to a webpage in the same site, from https://example.com/html1.html to https://example.com/html2.html. I also want it so the back button can be enabled, but from what I have found from searching nothing provides an answer for what I am looking for.

Here is code:

```js
location.href = "https://example.com/html2.html";
```

For some reason the back button to go to the previous page (https://example.com/html1.html) does not work.

```js
location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
//Firebase authstate changed listener here
//Timeout represents when the user signs in
setTimeout(() => {location.href = "https://example.com/";}, 500);
```

I have a hotfix which doesn't always work but it just puts a 1 sec delay and it works

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
        console.log("User: " + user.email + " Displayname: " + user.displayName);
        console.log("Url: " + location.href);
        console.log(location.href == "site1"); //Logging if we are in the site1 or not
        if (location.href == "site1") {
            setTimeout(() => {
                location.href = "site2";
            }, 1000);
            console.log("Not in site2");
        } else {
            console.log("In site2");
        }
        console.log("Going to main blog");
    }

});
```

Comment: No reason it shouldn't work. Open your console on this page and run `location.href = 'https://google.com'` and try back button from there. Should bring you back here

Comment: @charlietfl woah thats really weird. It didn't work on my webpage for some reason... I will check it out. It worked only once on my site... After I tried again it just stopped.
edit: Now its working again. Seems inconsistent or just could be because I am using firebase web hosting?

Comment: Can't see how host would make a difference when both urls resolve properly. Browser stores the history. Could be something to do with browser extensions perhaps. Try disabling them or see if you can replicate in incognito(private) mode

Comment: One other thing. You aren't using that right on page load are you?

Comment: @charlietfl no I am using it in firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged, but since the authstate is almost as instant as the on page load does it matter?

Comment: Hard to help without seeing a [mcve] that produces the issue. Is it possible you are coming back but something in that auth code is doing immediate redirect again?

Comment: @charlietfl sorry I didnt put an example. I can send a link to the site, but I will try editing the question for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Try
`window.location('link')`
should work